# Why restore and build are needed before publish in dockerfile autogenerated for .NET Core by VisualStudio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

VisualStudio generates Dockerfile for .NET Core like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/Sandbox/Sandbox.csproj", "src/Sandbox/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/Sandbox/Sandbox.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/Sandbox"
RUN dotnet build "Sandbox.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Sandbox.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Sandbox.dll"]
```

There are three different steps with SDK there:

- restore
- build
- publish

It looks like it can be simplified to one `publish` stage and get something like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS publish
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish "src/Sandbox/Sandbox.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Sandbox.dll"]
```

Is this separation in steps necessary to make it easier to customize each step in the future, or is there any other reason to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like they are trying to optimize things - by using docker caching and layering.

Splitting off restore from build/publish is a good idea. Your code changes often, but your project files and dependencies change little. Docker uses caching for things that don't change. If you can separate your project file from the rest of your code, you can cache the "restore" operation and make future builds faster.

See [build caching](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache) in the docker docs for more information about how this works.

Also take a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images?view=aspnetcore-5.0#the-dockerfile

I am not sure what this gets you:

```
RUN dotnet build "Sandbox.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Sandbox.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
```

I feel like the publish could be combined into the previous stage. I must be missing something.

Edit: On further thinking, perhaps this lets you use the cache (again!) while customizing how you publish?

For example, if you wanted to publish in self-contained mode, or target a different runtime id, you would just have to change the publish command and not the build command. If your application is large, that might save you some time.

Comment: Note that for this to work correctly, files have to be copied carefully before the restore step, as a `COPY . .` will invalidate all the cache for any file changed in that path

Comment: I'm still interested in why this is needed-- in older versions of CORE (<= 3.x?), `restore` was a separate command. >= 5, `restore` is baked into `build` and `publish`, and you actually have to pass in a `--no-restore` flag to skip restore during build and publish. So you lose any benefits from caching by causing yourself to restore 3 times. I could understand doing a restore first, then a publish with `--no-restore`

Answer (score 4):

Splitting into `restore`, `build`, and `publish` steps provides better caching of docker images at each of these steps.

For example, if the csproj file has not been modified, the cached image is used for the `restore` step instead of building a new one:

```
CACHED [build 4/7] RUN dotnet restore "src/Sandbox/Sandbox.csproj"
```

The same can be applied to the `build` step as long as there are no changes in all source files:

```
CACHED [build 7/7] RUN dotnet build "Sandbox.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
```

Comment: Why `build` before `publish`, though? `publish` is a specialized build and doesn't seem to use the output from the `build` step. I think the only reason to have it is if you actually use the output from `build` somehow, such as having an image that does not publish; that image can then be used for testing. A release image can be built on top of the original image with the nuget packages already on there (from `restore`) to ensure `publish` uses the same set of dependencies that the testing cycle used. But if you aren't doing that, a `restore` & `publish ... --no-restore` should suffice.